# Creating polygons for a choropleth map using PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, leaflet

I have a grid of points, each with a value to it as shown in the image below. The data was retrieved from PostGIS and rendered in Quantum GIS. The final result should be a polygons of a choropleth map that will be used to render on the browser.

**Question:** How can PostGIS use the grid of weighted points to create the choropleth polygons?

**Initial**
[image]

**Desired result**

Polygons to be created in PostGIS, rendered in Leaflet. Classes group according to some rule like:

```
d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
```

[image]

Comment: Of course it's possible that there will be more than one polygon for given value (they're not near by), rigth?